# Rails escapes HTML in my plain text mails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer, erb

I am using the rails 3.2.5 `ActionMailer` to send plain text mails. Given I have a mail view like this:

### `message_from_user.text.erb`:

```
Hi <%= @recipient.name %>,

You got the following message from <%= @sender.name %>:

<%= @message %>
```

When `@message` is `"quotes & ampersands"`, then the plain text mail contains `&quot;quotes &amp; ampersands&quot;`. So it seems like rails just treats this as a HTML view and escapes any html in order to prevent cross site scripting. However this is a plain text mail.  The extension is `.text.erb` and `ActionMailer` detectes this and sets the MIME to `text/plain`. So I never want to escape any html in it.

I have quite a few mail templates in my application, they are all plain text. I would consider patching all of them to include `<%=raw @message%>` or `<%= @message.html_safe %>` bad style - *not very DRY*.

I tried varios work-arounds that included money patching Erubis. None of them seem to work. I am looking for some patch or config option or anything to disable escaping html for all `.text.erb` files.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some hours of debugging through the Erubis code, I found the following fix. You can just put it into `config/initializers/fix_my_mails.rb`. I've tested this with rails 3.2.7. It may work with other versions.

```
module ActionView
  class Template
    module Handlers
      class ERB
        def call(template)
          if template.source.encoding_aware?
            # First, convert to BINARY, so in case the encoding is
            # wrong, we can still find an encoding tag
            # (<%# encoding %>) inside the String using a regular
            # expression
            template_source = template.source.dup.force_encoding("BINARY")

            erb = template_source.gsub(ENCODING_TAG, '')
            encoding = $2

            erb.force_encoding valid_encoding(template.source.dup, encoding)

            # Always make sure we return a String in the default_internal
            erb.encode!
          else
            erb = template.source.dup
          end

          self.class.erb_implementation.new(
            erb,
            :trim => (self.class.erb_trim_mode == "-"),
            :escape => template.identifier =~ /\.text/ # only escape HTML templates
          ).src
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

It just disables HTML entities in every erb file containing `.text` in the file name.

Answer (score 8):

Try

```
<%= @message.html_safe %>
```

You'd found this answer if you had used the search function. If that doesn't suit your needs, maybe check

https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/4858-actionmailer-is-html-escaping-ampersand-in-urls-in-plain-text-messages

If you haven't seen that yet, some options are discussed there

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but as stated in the question, this is not an option to me.  "[...] I would consider patching all of the to include <%=raw @message%> bad style - not very DRY."

Comment: Sorry, eating and reading at the same time doesn't seem to work as good as I expected ;) I added an additional likn, where this issue is discussed more deeply. If you haven't read that yet, maybe it helps